# MySQL - faster NOT EXISTS/EXISTS values from the same table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables: `tbl1` and `tbl2`. I want to return a single row from `tbl1` with columns: `col1`, `col2`, `col3`, `can_be_deleted`, `have_important_items`. The idea is that `can_be_deleted` and `have_important_items` columns are boolean values resulted (both) by searching in the same table `tbl2`.

```
SELECT
    col1,
    col2,
    col3,
    NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tbl2 WHERE mycategory=10 AND status>0 LIMIT 1) AS can_be_deleted,
    EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tbl2 WHERE mycategory=10 AND type_item>0 AND status>0 LIMIT 1) AS have_important_items 
FROM tbl1 WHERE ... LIMIT 1
```

To avoid later clarifications, `tbl2` columns are:

1. **mycategory** - a value to group items inside table
2. **status** - enabled/disabled item
3. **type_item** - 0-not important, >=1 important one (scale of importance)

Question: Can I write a faster query?

Comment: `indexing` is also a major role in your query `execution speed`

Comment: indeed, but I'm interested in whether a better syntax is possible.

Comment: Well you can start using ORDER BY <primary_key>  column with auto_increment option  when using LIMiT 1 to make sure you always get the “first” record.. This is needed because SQL tables and resultsets are by SQL standards defined as **orderless**

Comment: Also a NOT EXISTS can most likely be rewriten as a LEFT JOIN, which most likely is faster when indexed

Comment: Can `type_item` be `null`?

Comment: The two `EXISTS` clauses are not related to the main query. So all your result rows will have the same `can_be_deleted` and the same `have_important_items`. Is this desired?

Comment: On a side note: Don't use `LIMIT 1` inside an `EXISTS` clause. Tell the DBMS *what* to do, not *how* to do it.

Answer (score 0):

using JOIN is faster than EXIST,check if this query solve your probleme and if not then just change the conditions to get your result.
**"t1.t2_id" is the foreign key of tbl2, change it to the correct name**

```
SELECT
    col1,
    col2,
    col3,
    LEFT JOIN tbl2 AS t2 ON t2.id = t1.t2_id
    WHERE t2.mycategory = 10
    AND t2.status>0
    AND t2.type_item>0 
    FROM tbl1 AS t1 WHERE ... LIMIT 1
```